# `delete this` returns true despite not deleting the object reference

Tags: javascript

I just opened chrome dev tools on stackoverflow.com and typed in the console the following

```
delete this;
```

Which returned true despite not deleting the reference.

**Why does delete return true if it didn't delete anything?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `delete` operator in javascript has nothing to do with memory management, you can't use it to delete objects.

Quote from [Mozilla delete page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Description):

> Unlike what common belief suggests, the delete operator has nothing to do with directly freeing memory.

You can use the delete operator only to remove properties from an object, e.g:

```js
let obj = {a: 1, b: 2};
console.log(delete obj.a); // true
console.log(obj); // {b: 2}
```

#### Why `delete` returns true

`delete` will **always** return true, unless the property you tried to delete is non-configurable and you aren't in strict mode (delete throws in strict mode). This includes the case where you call delete with an expression that doesn't resolve in a property reference, e.g. `this` or `null`, etc...

Example:

```js
// Doesn't evaluate to propery access.
// But isn't a non-configurable property, so return true
console.log(delete null); // true
console.log(delete 12); // true
console.log(delete "foobar"); // true

// non-configurable own property.
// only case when delete returns false
// (or throws in strict mode)
let obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, "val", {value: 12});
console.log(delete obj.val); // false
```